# Is "Very many mails in the mailqueue" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Does the following phrase use the plural form 'mails' correctly?

> Very many mails in the mailqueue.

Comment: You have no verb for one thing, so its not a sentence.

Comment: Context would help a lot, here. Is this an intended message for the User Interface of a program or website, or is it meant to be a regular sentence in English?

I would word it as, "Your mailbox is full", or, "The mailqueue is almost full." I don't see any justifiable reason to say,  "You have a lot of mail." It sounds silly, and also is not very helpful, as "many" is completely subjective.

Please, update your question and provide the context to what exactly, precisely you are trying to say.

Comment: I would use "A great many" or "A lot" instead. Just style though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Very many* is grammatical, and there are [a good many](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/a-good-many) instances of it in literature; however, there are [many many](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/many) more instances of *[great many](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/a-good-or-great-many)*:

[image: Google Books NGram showing relative popularity of different ways to emphasize 'many']

I would adjudge *very many* on its own to be uncommon enough to be distracting these days. Still, there aren't very many who would dispute the validity of *not very many*, especially in its contracted form. It even appears in an [example OALD sentence](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/many):

> We don't have very many copies left.

I have no theories as to the apparent decline of all these expressions over the last few decades, except that there are a fair number of ways to express the concept, and a whole lot of less formal expressions may have greater acceptance now than they did in the past.

Comment: Ngrams on a phone is a pain the posterior end, so I can't easily verify, but I would suspect most of the Ngram examples of _very many_ are in fact from _not very many_. In my experience at least, _very many_ used the way it's used in the asker's phrase here is **extremely** unusual, to the point of being ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

As a sentence, no, it is not grammatically correct, for a few reasons; however, the construction "very many" is not one of them.

1. "mail" is a mass noun. Countable units of mail might be letters, parcels, packages -- or, since I suspect this is in an electronic mail, computer context, "e-mails" (or "emails").
2. The sentence has no verb; it isn't a sentence. Adding "There are..." the the beginning fixes that.
3. "mailqueue" is not a standard english word; I suspect you're referring to the email concept. If not, you may need a different word.

"very many" is not itself ungrammatical, but it is stylistically questionable; editors would likely complain about an article that used that phrase. If the "many" is so many that it bears emphasis, perhaps one should be more precise; is "very many" here dozens? thousands? billions?

Comment: R H K Webster's gives 'mail' as a shortened form of 'e-mail', which implies the count usage is acceptable. (It actually mentions 'mails' for another sense.)

Comment: "mail" as a short form of the *verb* e-mail I totally agree with.  But the noun? Well, I don't hear it used that way. (Noun "mails" for the sense of the postal system, just as "maths", seems to me fine in British English but not American.)

Comment: A major dictionary giving the usage trumps 'I don't hear it being used that way'. Although I haven't heard that usage either, I'll accept the results of the statistical analyses on the corpora Webster's uses.

Comment: I have heard _mails_ used as a plural noun to mean _e-mails_ on many occasions. It is not uncommon at all. _Mail queue_ is also a fairly common term, though it's jargon and usually written as two words.

Comment: I have heard this error many times as well. I also hear people use  "install" as a noun, and "login" as a verb. That don't make it right.

Comment: Edwin: certainly, but your original comment wasn't clear about whether you mean as a noun. And anyway, I wasn't saying "I don't hear it that way" as conclusive; but this site, as dictionary researchers, relies on people giving their personal understanding of the language.

Answer (score 0):

*Very many* is incorrect in this context. It is better to say

> There are a lot of mails in the mail queue.

Note that *mail queue* is two words.

Answer (score 0):

"Mails" is not the plural of "mail", because "mail" is a mass noun, not a count noun.

Likewise,  "emails" is not the plural of "email", because "email" is a mass noun, not a count noun.

And yet, the majority of people, who, I presume, would not refer to several letters in their physical mailbox as a lot of, or many, or very many "mails", nevertheless persist in pluralizing "email".

The electronic equivalent of a letter is an **email message**. The plural form is **email messages** (or simply **messages**.)

As they say

- it ain't the things you don't know that get you in trouble; it's what you do know that ain't so.